# Dojo: create programatically a menu in an enhancedgrid

Tags: dojo, grid, menuitem

I'm trying to create programatically an EnahncedGrid with a menu. I've got the grid to work, but I've been unable to use the menu. It just not shows up. The code is as follows:

```
<script>
sMenu = new dijit.Menu({});
      sMenu.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
          label: "Delete Record",
          iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCancel",
          onClick : function(){
              alert(1);
          }
      }));
sMenu.startup();


/**
 * El grid propiamente dicho
 */
var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
 id: "grid_"+i,
 query: {
              idDocument: '*'
          },
          plugins: {
           nestedSorting: true,
           indirectSelection: true,
           menus: {rowMenu:sMenu}
          },
          onRowDblClick: openFile,
          structure: layout
      })
</script>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this myself, but I have two possible suggestions:

First, make sure you're `dojo.require`-ing `"dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Menu"` and are only instantiating the widgets within a `dojo.addOnLoad` or `dojo.ready`.

If you've already done that, the second thing I'd suggest is giving your menu an id, and passing that id to the `rowMenu` property of the `menus` object (in other words, pass a string, not the widget itself).  Although, the way you're doing it seems like it should work, judging from the code.

You can see a test page with working menus here: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/enhanced/test_enhanced_grid_menus.html

Comment: Well, the grid and the menu works if I declare them using tags (<div>) so there is no issue with the library. The problem is that the grid and the menus should be created programatically, because they can change according to the user's actions. The example you gave works, but it is not programatic, so it doesn't help. I will try to pass the String, I suppouse I need to declare an Id for the menu and use that id as the rowMenu, right?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed, you might not be calling `grid.startup()` after instantiating your grid programmatically?  Try that.

Comment: I forgot to copy that, but it is done(the startup, I mean). The grid works fine, it's just the menu that is no showing up. BTW, I test passing the id to the grid, instead of the actual widget, but it still does not work.

Comment: Okay, I just tried it myself - this is going to sound insane, but it seems to me like it works so long as you supply a srcNodeRef to the EnhancedGrid constructor (rather than simply `placeAt` the grid afterwards).  See: http://jsfiddle.net/kfranqueiro/DkJZA/

Comment: It does sound insane, but works. Thank you!!! How the hell did you figure it out?

Comment: Actually it was pretty much just my next random thought as it occurred, but I had already written up the fiddle by then anyway to try it. :P  Also FWIW you can pass either an id or widget reference to `rowMenu`, either one does work.  I just checked on dojo's trunk - it looks like this got resolved there, though there appears to be an interesting little quirk where you need to actually select a row before the right-click menu will work.

Comment: Last question. The grid should appear in a ContentPane, so I create the pane doing var pane = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({ title:labelValue, jsId : "myPane", closable:false }); and the grid = dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({...},pane.domNode). The pane is shown, but not the grid. How can I fix that?

Comment: I think by doing that you're ending up actually clobbering your ContentPane widget's topmost node *with* the grid's - and depending on which you call startup on when, one or the other will win.  Try putting a div inside your ContentPane and then using that as the srcNodeRef for the grid instead?